# Using Spring Boot Async creates suspended threads

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am using Spring Boot `2.1.5.RELEASE`, and using `@Async`.  However, when the `@Async` method is executed, it creates a new suspended thread every time.

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class MyConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (throwable, method, objects) -> {
            logger.error("Error: ", throwable);
        };
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
...
@Async
@Transactional
public Integer insertToTable(Foo foo) {
    // Table insert logic ...
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1).join();
}
...
```

But when the method `insertToTable` is triggered, it adds a suspended thread:

[image: Suspended Threads]

Is my setup is wrong?  Please help me out!

Comment: What behavior do you expect ? Thread pool creates a new thread up to max pool size. When thread completes it task it waits for keepAliveSeconds in order to be reused(which can be configured using setKeepAliveSeconds) and then thread is stopped. By default threads wait for 1 minutes (60 seconds)

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak Aha, so that's the expected behavior. Could you add that as comment? I want to mark your comment as answer

Comment: I posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected behavior. 
 Thread pool creates a new thread up to max pool size. When thread completes it task it waits for keepAliveSeconds in order to be reused(which can be configured using setKeepAliveSeconds) and then thread is stopped. By default threads wait for 1 minutes (60 seconds)